# How to resolve re-login to Remote Desktop Client with Remmina?

Tags: windows, server, remote-access, remote-server, remote-desktop

I used Remmina to join to remote windows server

But I have a little problem

once I close remote windows, I cannot go to remote windows server again with remmina

for resolving this problem, I have to open Vmware and open "browser console" and login to windows server
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhd6N.jpg)

and with this activity, my log and cache clear and I can log in again

Now my question is: How can I resolve this problem and close and open repeatedly my windows server in remmina

Notice: I don't have this problem on Linux server with remmina and this problem occurred in windows server with remmina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem
we should use this command in CMD to resolve problems like this

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

then, you have to see users list and if you have two different users remove one of them, for example, if you login with Administrator user, remove another username and reboot your system

thanks for watching this question